# Deleting a remote branch with Egit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am using EGit 3.2 with Eclipse.  I cannot figure out how to delete a branch from my remote repository.  I'm working on a Drupal project and the mods there want me to delete the master branch. I have the version specific branch (7.x-1.x) set up and on the server.  When I go to the Git perspective and delete the master branch from the remote tracking section, the branch disappears but not from the server.  I've tried deleting and then pushing the project back up to no avail.

I've also tried it from the PHP perspective by going to Team --> Advanced --> Delete Branch and selecting the master branch.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go in your menu to Team > Remote > Push.

Select your repository, and click Next.

Under Remote ref to delete - select your branch and click Add spec. Then Finish.

This will delete the remote branch.